# Turn Date into Column with Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Im not good at using Pivot but i think that's the only way to solve my Problem.

I have this SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR
, LEFT(ADR_Adressen.Name, 3) AS Name
, LEFT(ADR_Adressen.Vorname, 3) AS Vorname
, CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon
, LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG
, CRM_AufgabenLink.MitNrPRO
FROM  ADR_Adressen
    INNER JOIN PRO_Auftraege ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR = PRO_Auftraege.Kunde
    INNER JOIN CRM_Aufgaben ON PRO_Auftraege.AuftragNrPRO = CRM_Aufgaben.AuftragNrPRO
    INNER JOIN CRM_Status ON CRM_Aufgaben.StatusCRM = CRM_Status.StatusCRM
    INNER JOIN LAG_Artikel ON CRM_Aufgaben.ArtikelNrLAG = LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG
    INNER JOIN ADR_GruppenLink ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR = ADR_GruppenLink.AdressNrADR
    INNER JOIN ADR_Gruppen ON ADR_GruppenLink.GruppeADR = ADR_Gruppen.GruppeADR
    INNER JOIN CRM_AufgabenLink ON CRM_Aufgaben.AufgabenNrCRM = CRM_AufgabenLink.AufgabenNrCRM
WHERE  { d '2016-03-07'} <= CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon
   AND { d '2016-03-11'} + 1 >= CRM_Aufgaben.TerminBis
   AND CRM_AufgabenLink.MitNrPRO != 0
   AND ADR_Gruppen.GruppeADR IN ( 'KIND' )
```

This is my result:

[image]

My wish is to get a Output like this:
[image]

The different Dates in TerminVon has to be Columns with the Values from ArtikelNrLAG+MitNrPRO. If the same AdressNrADR has more then one TerminVon on the same Date i have to make more rows. (Example where Name = Boc,Alt)

Can someone help me please =)

Comment: Nice job posting the query you have tried and desired output. It would really help if you could post a table with the results of this query. That way we have something to work with so we can help you here. Just create a temp table or something and provide the insert statement to populate it with data. Then we can work on your actual problem.

Comment: I was just going to ask for the same.

Comment: @SeanLange  How can i do that fast? Im using 8 tables in my query...

Comment: i've never seen `{ d '2016-03-11'}` before.. i should be asking YOU questions..

Comment: @JamieD77 those are ODBC escapes. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190234%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a create table statement. This doesn't have to use your existing tables. It just needs to get into a table that we can work with. Then turn the results into an insert statement.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to start you on your way  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/910b7/3

Answer (score 2):

To `PIVOT` what you have, you can use a query similar to this.

```
SELECT  AdressNrADR,  
        Name,
        Vorname,
        [2016-03-07],
        [2016-03-08],
        [2016-03-09],
        [2016-03-10],
        [2016-03-11]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR,
            LEFT(ADR_Adressen.Name,3) AS Name,
            LEFT(ADR_Adressen.Vorname,3) AS Vorname,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon, 120) AS TerminVon, -- Convert date to yyyy-mm-dd format
            LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG + '+' + CRM_AufgabenLink.MitNrPRO AS [Value], -- Combine column values
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                (PARTITION BY AdressNrADR, 
                              LEFT(ADR_Adressen.Name,3), 
                              LEFT(ADR_Adressen.Vorname,3), 
                              CAST(CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon AS DATE) 
                        ORDER BY CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon) Rn -- So we can get 1 row per time value
    FROM    ADR_Adressen
            INNER JOIN PRO_Auftraege ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR = PRO_Auftraege.Kunde
            INNER JOIN CRM_Aufgaben ON PRO_Auftraege.AuftragNrPRO = CRM_Aufgaben.AuftragNrPRO
            INNER JOIN CRM_Status ON CRM_Aufgaben.StatusCRM = CRM_Status.StatusCRM
            INNER JOIN LAG_Artikel ON CRM_Aufgaben.ArtikelNrLAG = LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG
            INNER JOIN ADR_GruppenLink ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR = ADR_GruppenLink.AdressNrADR
            INNER JOIN ADR_Gruppen ON ADR_GruppenLink.GruppeADR = ADR_Gruppen.GruppeADR
            INNER JOIN CRM_AufgabenLink ON CRM_Aufgaben.AufgabenNrCRM = CRM_AufgabenLink.AufgabenNrCRM
    WHERE   { d '2016-03-07'} <= CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon
            AND { d '2016-03-11'} + 1 >= CRM_Aufgaben.TerminBis
            AND CRM_AufgabenLink.MitNrPRO != 0
            AND ADR_Gruppen.GruppeADR IN ('KIND') 
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value]) 
    FOR TerminVon IN ([2016-03-07],[2016-03-08],[2016-03-09],[2016-03-10],[2016-03-11])
) p
```

If you get that query to work.  Your next step would be to make it Dynamic.

Comment: Thank you so much, your my hero. this is a really good start. Do i have to make it Dynamic? { d '2016-03-07'} <= CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon
            AND { d '2016-03-11'} + 1 >= CRM_Aufgaben.TerminBis always Shows me the start date and end date. It's always gonna be 5 Dates mon-fri

Comment: if you are going to put this sql into a stored procedure, then you will need a way to replace `[2016-03-07],[2016-03-08],[2016-03-09],[2016-03-10],[2016-03-11]` when the week changes..

Answer (score 0):

The difficult part of using t-sql's pivot functionality is that the output column names have to be hard coded.  In your example we would need to know the value of each date and use that in the query in order to get the matching values by date.  Fortunately other fine developers have experienced this frustration for us and have created scripts that will generate a dynamic pivot.  I have included two links that will help you on your way.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: My Dates will always be the Dates BETWEEN TerminVon - TerminBis

Comment: You still need to hard code them as ouput columns though